# Sticky Navbar offset to prevent overlap of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently on my single page site when you click on the Bootstrap navbar menu items it takes you to the section of the page with that div #ID. However, naturally because the top of the navbar lines up with the top of the new section my content is overlapped by the width of the navbar (80px or 50px when collapsed).

Screenshot of issue: [image: Screenshot]

"Ready to book" heading is actually centered in the middle of that div but overlapped by 80px of navbar.

Screenshot showing top of page:
[image: Top of page]

**The issue is** that I do not wish for the navbar to overlap the content in the section I have linked to. Put in other words, I would like the top of bottom of the navbar to line up with the top of the new section div.

Surely this can be handled using some JS to offset the navbar up by the height of the the navbar?

I have had a suggestion to use CSS to add padding into the top of section but this adds an extra 80px of padding that I don't want, when normally scrolling the page.

Comment: Please show  code you tried.

Comment: I have not tried in JS as not sure where to start, therefore no code. The navbar links just href directly to the div #ID. It defaults to having this overlap currently.

Comment: Thanks @Dien, the problem with that is that the navbar is not fixed at the top of the page initially, as per this screenshot. [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p20f00gf4wxa50w/Screenshot%202015-11-28%2014.12.42.png?dl=0) Sorry I can't comment on your post Dien for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found two solution to this finally using JS and CSS
[here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768).

**My preference is for this CSS solution:**

```
#id:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Obviously, replace ID with the ID of the anchor.

**The actual JS snippet solution:**

```
var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50) };
window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
function load() { if (window.location.hash) shiftWindow(); }
```

However, it is still a bit clunky as you can actually see the the browser scroll to the anchor point and then back up by the scrollBy offset amount of 80px.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this problem has been solved yet, but I had the same problem and adding the appropriate heading worked (by appropriate padding I mean the height of your navbar element).

For example:

```
#id { padding:50px }
```